# What does -Wformat=2 do?

Tags: xcode, warnings, clang, string-formatting, compiler-warnings

I'm seeing numerous mentions on the web of a `-Wformat=2` option to Clang, sometimes alongside the already-known `-Wformat` (the one that Xcode lists as “Typecheck calls to `printf`/`scanf`, although it covers many more string-formatting APIs now).

- Does this do anything at all?
- If it does, what, if anything, does it do differently from `-Wformat`?
- Is it useful to have both, or is either one a superset of the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If it does, what, if anything, does it do differently from -Wformat?

It's borrowed from GCC, as it is designed to be a suitable drop in replacement. [GCC's description](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options):

> **-Wformat=2**
>
> *Enable -Wformat plus format checks not included in -Wformat. Currently
>   equivalent to `-Wformat -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security
>   -Wformat-y2k'.*

That answers most of your questions.

> Does this do anything at all?

Yes. The following program emits different warnings, depending on the presence (or absence) of `-Wformat=2`:

```
__attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, 1, 2)))
static void F(const char* const pString, ...) {
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    F("", 0);
    F(argv[0], 0);
    const char str[] = "aaa";
    F(str, 0);
    F("%i", 0);
    F("%i");
    return 0;
}
```

Note: It appears Clang rolls `-Wformat-security` into `-Wformat`.

Finally, I've not tested `-Wformat-y2k`, but it is defined by GCC as:

> **-Wformat-y2k**
>
> *If -Wformat is specified, also warn about strftime formats which may yield only a two-digit year.*

Comment: `-Wformat-y2k` appears to be unimplemented in Clang; I just tried it with a program that uses a `%y` (year of century) conversion specifier, and got no complaint. Thanks.